# Jailbreakme comptible with xcode development ? (profiles....)

Tags: xcode, jailbreak

Before jailbreaking my iPhone with jailbreakme I would like to be sure that it will not be an issue to run on my iPhone the applications I develop with xcode. Will it be an issue for the development profiles installed on my iPhone ? Etc...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any issue at all.